# OwnCloud has issues with HEIC files. How to fix this?

Tags: owncloud

I installed OwnCloud onto an Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

Everything works so far, no unmet dependencies, so it's all good.

However, whenever I upload a *HEIC* file:

> [image]

I have more problems with this:

1. No thumbnail is created
2. Preview is not possible (like with JPG, PNG, etc)
3. During download, OC skips the file extension: so above file will be downloaded as `IMG_5248` binary file.

OwnCloud is latest, and I couldn't find any solution which is recent.

Download problem seems to be related with my Firefox, as requests and responses are fine, but still, FF downloads it without extension:

> [image]

Comment: You can check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/965306/680869

Comment: I don't have GUI on the server. On my computer which is also Ubuntu, I can open HEIC files without problems, but via the webUI of OC, I can't open it. What do you suggest especially? Thank you!

Comment: Daniel, my idea is to install the library and add it (somehow) to the Owncloud software. As I see Owncloud is `php` based so adding new library should not be so big problem.

Comment: My biggest problem is #3, and I just have realized, that my FF seems buggy in this manner.

Comment: SE is oriented to one question - one answer. Maybe will be wise to split your question to 3.